# VBA to group similar data with a new parent row

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with unique numbers in column A that I want to group together with a parent row displayed. For example:

[image]

I want it to display like this with the comments grouped (shift+alt+right in excel) underneath its unique number.

[image]

Collapsed, it will look like:

[image]

The plus signs not actually being in the cell but just showing that there are child rows underneath the parent.hoping for an answer. thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is more suited to using Excel filters rather than VBA. But if you really want to use VBA, the code below does what you describe and perhaps you can use it as a starting point to reach your goal.

The .select statements should all be removed. They are just there so you can learn what the code does as you step through as in the animated gif which shows the code working. Then, at the end a right click around the hidden rows is used to unhide them.

[image]

```
Option Explicit
Sub groupAndHideRows()
Dim sh As Worksheet, r As Range
Set sh = ActiveSheet
'group rows
Set r = sh.Range("A1")
While r <> ""
    sh.Rows(r.Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    r.Select
    r.Offset(-1, 0) = Left(r, 5)
    While Left(r, 5) = Left(r.Offset(1, 0), 5)
        Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
        r.Select
    Wend
    Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
Wend
'hide rows
Set r = sh.Range("A1")
While r <> ""
    r.Select
    If Not IsNumeric(r) Then sh.Rows(r.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
Wend
End Sub
```